# KDE connect indicator not showing on tray

Tags: lubuntu, synaptic, kde-connect

I installed KDE indicator through [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) a couple days ago. Everything works great except for a few times where my device wont show up on PC (solved with a reboot)

I installed the KDE indicator through the terminal. If I launch it normally from **menu > preferences**, I  get nothing. 
It shows up as a running process in task manager, but no user interface is shown.
I can't access/use any of its features.
Is there a solution? is it cause KDE-connect came from synaptic and KDE indicator came from apt-get?

I'm running Lubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue on Lubuntu 18.04.

I have managed to send files from my PC to a paired Android devices using the command line utility from kde connect. To see the options available, open up a terminal and type

```
kdeconnect-cli
```

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on 18.04

I made the KDE Connect show up by sending a file from my phone to my computer. It automatically put the file in Downloads and added the KDE icon to the task bar. [image]

Comment: Didn't work for me, I sent a file. My computer receives the file, but the tray icon doesn't show up. I now use the CLI as Henrique suggested above, works for me. I prefer command line anyway. I'm also on 18.04 LTS.